# After changing any setting in Woocommerce plugin I get Error 404 Page not found for every page from menu (except main page)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-404, polylang

Hello I have `Wordpress 6.4.2` and `Woocommerce 8.4.0` and basically after any change in `Woocommerce` settings (for example just changing `Settings->General->Thousand separator` from `,` to `'`) and saving it leaded to `Error 404 page not found` for every page from menu (except main page).

Workaround was for me to always `disable` and `re-enable` `Woocommerce` plugin and then it luckily started to works always... But it was very annoying...

So what may be the reason for 404 error after any change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So suspicion was that it started to happening after my colleague had a cleaning day and deleted unused german translation for `Woocommerce` pages for `Shop`, `Basket`, `Checkout` and `My account`.

There is useful menu `Woocommerce->Status` where it was in red that `Polylang` is missing translations for those pages. Since we are not using more languages now, I just disabled plugins:

- Polylang for WooCommerce | Version 1.7 | By WP SYNTEX
- Polylang Pro | Version 3.4.1 | By WP SYNTEX

And now it seems all works flawlessly.

(Also to be complete Woocommerce was missing also english link to "Terms and conditions" which I did add also. But I think it was not a main thing that fixed that error...)

Anyway maybe this tip will help, otherwise good luck hunting reasons for yours 404...